# Properly typing a generator function that calls another generator function in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, generator

I have a utility function which is a generator, like this:

```
function* myGenerator(): Generator<Foo, void> {
  ... // yield Foos
}
```

Now I want to wrap this utility function in a class, like this:

```
class MyWrapper {
  *generator(): Generator<Foo, void> {
    // call utils.myGenerator();
  }
}
```

The problem is: If I type `MyWrapper.generator()` as a generator with the `*` notation, I cannot simply implement it as `return utils.myGenerator()`, because a generator function *returns* void, and I will get a `Type Generator<Foo, void> is not assignable to void` error.

I can remove the `*` from `MyWrapper.generator()`, have the return type be `Generator<Foo, void>`, and return `utils.myGenerator()`:

```
class MyWrapper {
  generator(): Generator<Foo, void> {
    return utils.myGenerator();
  }
}
```

... but losing `*` makes it less clear for the caller that this is a generator function (granted, the return type should give it away, but still).

I can also iterate through the "inner" generator and yield everything from it:

```
class MyWrapper {
  *generator(): Generator<Foo, void> {
    for (const x of utils.myGenerator()) {
      yield x;
    }
  }
}
```

... but this extra yielding layer seems silly.

Is there an obvious way I'm missing to have a generator function wrap another generator function and still maintain the `*` notation, such as a "yield everything from" syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `yield*` to yield all elements of another generator

```
type Foo = string
function* myGenerator(): Generator<Foo, void> {
    yield "A";
    yield "B";
}


class MyWrapper {
  *generator(): Generator<Foo, void> {
    yield* myGenerator();
  }
}

console.log([...new MyWrapper().generator()]) // ["A", "B"]
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=5&ssc=2&pln=6&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBnYAnAlgOwOYBQAZgK44DGwWcOAVFALYgDiEOEGAhsHBgBQBKAFxRW7LjwwAeeHAA0UAG5wsAEwB8UAN4EoeqCCwQANqqgAiAILmA3Lv2GTZ8wCFbBAL4Fv5Y51SoUACyIADqXGCQGNr2tHhsHNy8giJiiZIyCArKapo6+gZGpvRMaRLJAnZ6Xl4E5DSocMYQAHTGcHh8ANotvewA7sFhEVGCLfHiSfwCALoCQA)

Comment: See, this is what I was after, I knew there was a way to "yield all", but it was too far back in my mind. Thanks!